# Why is the python smtplib module running slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

I am using the python module `smtplib` to send emails and i have been able to send emails for a while just fine but now when I try to login it takes a while when it used to take seconds.

```py
import smtplib

mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()

mail.login(email,password)
mail.close()
```

Also yes i do have less secure apps allowed for my email, Could it have something to do with the fact that I ran it a few times without `mail.close()`

Comment: The duration of login is controlled by the server and the network connection; smtplib can only send the request and wait for a response.

Comment: But if you have been logging in repeatedly, it is quite plausible that Gmail is rate-limiting you; they do that sort of thing.